# jsPDF, insert image with customized styles

Tags: jspdf, angular9

I need to make pdf with uploaded user avatar by using jsPDF. There is my code:

```
public openPDF(): void {
const elem = document.getElementById('AddNewBtn');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

let imgData = this.selectedFile.src;

const data = document.getElementById('htmlData');
html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
  console.log(canvas);
  const imgWidth = 160;
  const heightLeft = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 160, 15, 50, 50);
  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 5, 25, 200, 210);
  pdf.save('invoice.pdf');
});}
```

I got it like this:[image]

instead of to be inside grey circle the image is placed behind the page layout! Could you please help me to fix this issue ? I need to get this result:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine with me after cleaning cash and restarting application! I just delete addImage and got my desired result!